# How can a Custom Framework be used instead of .NET in Visual Studio for C# projects?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

*Disclaimer: I have only two day's experience trying to learn modern MSBuild techniques, but have used C# and VS for many years largely avoiding project file details outside of what the UI provides.*

I am creating experimental DLLs that *intentionally* name-match and somewhat interface-match several of those found in the [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard). For instance a custom **System.IO.dll** may partially match the public interface of .NET's **System.IO.dll**, same with **mscorlib.dll**, etc.

The goal is to be able to create a new C# project (File->New->Project->...) and have it link to these alternatives DLLs and *not* the official DLLs. This has been done successfully from the command-line using csc.exe, but not yet from within VS.

Using *detailed* build output verbosity in VS (Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run) shows that the numerous DLLs within .NET are added to the csc.exe command-line. Perhaps if this could be prevented all would be well. One failed attempt to do so involved removing the `<TargetFramework>` altogether.

Maybe registering a "custom framework" with Visual Studio would allow a custom value to be used within csproj, e.g.`<TargetFramework>mydotnet</TargetFramework>`?

All just guesses.

It seems MSBuild is very rich and would allow for multiple ways to achieve such a thing. I am completely receptive to learning one or more of these techniques, since one may provide advantages for future build customization plans.

Answer (score 1):

> How can a Custom Framework be used instead of .NET in Visual Studio for C# projects?

To use a Custom Framework instead of .NET in Visual Studio for C# projects, you have to do a lot of things, Registering Framework, Create a Template for Project and so on. So, Are you really writing your own implementation of the framework? If you just want to add your own libraries to an existing Framework, you can refer to following thread:

[Registering Extensions of the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee722096.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Besides, there is a document about [How to: Add a Custom ASP.NET MVC Test Framework in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416508(v=vs.98).aspx), you can check it for details.

Comment: I found this question looking to do just that. There's an API-definition-level bug in the reference assemblies. Rather than stomp the system copies I'd choose to point the build at a custom copy so that resolving the framework actually resolves the locally compiled copy.